# CakePHP 3.0 baking in netbeans

Tags: cakephp, netbeans, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

I am using CakePHP 3.0 for my first project and using Netbeans IDE.
I downloaded CakePHP 3 plugin from [github : junichi11](http://github.com/junichi11/cakephp3-netbeans).

Project is running well in browser. But unable to use bake command.

On running bake command from `right click on project >> CakePHP3 >> run command` and selecting bake all gives a list of possible models and there is no input console to make selection or enter any command.

[image: bake command output]

**Baking from terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 gives this**
[*commands are highlighted in yellow*]

[image: baking from terminal]

How to run command like `cake bake all admins`

Comment: Why do not run it from the terminal?

Comment: @rrd running from terminal gives error. The output screenshot has been added to the question. See updated question.

Comment: on Ubuntu php cli runs on different permission than php. It seems it has no read access to those files

Comment: Yet another "I don't read error messages" question. Just read the message of the fatal error! It already tells you what you need to check and do!

Comment: as Fatal error, I created a core.php in config directory and now this error has gone but a new error is there `Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/flickfix.com/public_html/admin2/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/flickfix.com/public_html/admin2/flickfix_admin2/config/bootstrap.php `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to fill the `parameters` field

[image: Answer on screen]